# Sending UTF-8 email through Postfix sendmail utility

Tags: utf-8, sendmail, postfix-mta

I have an application that submits email through the Postfix sendmail utility using the -t option.

We're looking to accommodate utf-8 subject lines and addresses. My understanding is the fields should be encoded as MIME-Header (RFC 2047)?

It appears, however, that sendmail does not recognize that encoding. Mail bounces with e.g.,:

**Jan  1 12:23:19 lando postfix/local[3173514]: 3659C1182E4C: to==?UTF-8?B?TWF1cmljZSDDocK8wojDj8KBw4/Ch8OOwrnDjsK8w6HCvcK1w47CtMOOwrc=?=@lando, orig_to=<=?UTF-8?B?TWF1cmljZSDDocK8wojDj8KBw4/Ch8OOwrnDjsK8w6HCvcK1w47CtMOOwrc=?=>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "=?utf-8?b?twf1cmljzsddock8wojdj8kbw4/ch8oowrndjsk8w6hcvck1w47ctmoowrc=?=")**

So it seems to be interpreting the recipient address as a local address.

Is there a way to have sendmail interpret that encoding or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't MIME-encode email address. Support for "Internationalized Email Headers" is described in [RFC 6532](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6532). You need to make sure that all SMTP servers your emails are going through support [SMTP Extension for Internationalized Email](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6531). See also [Overview and Framework for Internationalized Email](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6530)